# how to check all selected options in multiple select field in EJS

Tags: javascript, express, template-engine, ejs

i want to know the best practice to check all selected options in my select option when data is edited.

i have select option tag which supports multiple select:

```
<select name="tags[]" class="multi-select" multiple="" id="mytags" >

    <% tags.map((t)=>{ %>
        <option  value="<%= t.tagName %>"><%= t.tagName %>    </option>
    <% }) %>

</select>
```

> my question:
>
> 1. does ejs have built-in tag to automatically select the all selected options ?
> 2. what is the best practice to handle this case?
>
> your answer will help me to understand better.

Comment: is my question stupid? so that you gimme down vote? i really dont know how to solve it, i am newbie i have searched on google, read some articles but no one solves my problem. 

if i am wasting your time, please dont do it, just ignore my question. i appreciate your time sir, really appreciate, please dont down vote.

Comment: i open advices from you guys to make me better programmer, if i am asking stupid question please gimme advices what should i learn to make my programming skill better, i really wanna be good programmer, gimme advices sir.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use

- `<option selected value="<%= t.tagName %>"><%= t.tagName %></option>`

OR

- `<option selected="selected" value="<%= t.tagName %>"><%= t.tagName %></option>`

Comment: i did sir, both of your examples are same as mine. could u give me more explanation sir?

Comment: owh yeah, i know it but what i wanna know is how to check all selected options which have been chose by the user then display it ?

Comment: <option value="1" <%= config[0].volume == '1' ? 'selected' : ''%>>1</option>